# Java Canvas Zooming in Flickering

Tags: java, zooming, flicker, doublebuffered, java-canvas

I'm working on a project that requires me to be able to zoom in and out on a Canvas. I'm using the method:

```
setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * scale, HEIGHT * scale));
```

and from there just modifying the scale variable. This works, except most of the time I will get an annoying flicker. It's triple buffered, so I don't really understand how it could take that long to transform the canvas to the proper size...

Anyway, if there's something I'm missing, I'd love to know.

Here's my update() method:

```
public void update() {
    updateCount++;

    if (input.mouseWheel.getNotchesMoved() != 0 && SCALE >= MIN_SCALE
            && SCALE <= MAX_SCALE) {
        SCALE += input.mouseWheel.getNotchesMoved();
        if (SCALE > MAX_SCALE)
            SCALE = MAX_SCALE;
        if (SCALE < MIN_SCALE)
            SCALE = MIN_SCALE;
        setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    }
    input.refresh();
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Tree

EDIT: When I say "Canvas", I mean java.awt.Canvas, the base class of the main class, sorry about any confusion.

Comment: What's the base component your extending from?

Comment: I'm extending Canvas, I'll make that a bit more obvious, sorry.

Comment: Are you adding this `Canvas` to `JFrame`?

Comment: Yeah, I mean the graphics work perfectly fine, it's just that I'm getting flickering when I zoom in.

Comment: It could be an issue between heavy and light weight components.  What are you adding the `Canvas` to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18349/discussion-between-treesin-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: You're mixing heavy and light weight components together, this is never really a good idea.  Instead of extending from `Canvas` try extending from `JPanel` instead